# Parsing with Boost Spirit, getting extra items

Tags: parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

This is long with a lot of code, so I hope Stack Overflow can cope with it. :P

I'm trying to write an SVG parser with Boost Spirit.  I have a grammar that populates a vector with "Contours," which are vectors of "BezierPoints," which may represent either regular points or points with bezier controls.

So far I have this (not handling relative draw commands yet):

```
#ifndef SVG_PARSER_HPP
#define SVG_PARSER_HPP

#include <vector>

#include "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"
#include "boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp"

#include "boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp"
#include "boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp"

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

struct Point
{
    Point(const double nx = 0.0, const double ny = 0.0) : x(nx), y(ny)
    {}

    double x;
    double y;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Point,
    (double, x)
    (double, y)
)

struct BezierPoint
{
    BezierPoint(const double x = 0.0, const double y = 0.0) :
      point(x, y), control1(0.0, 0.0), control2(0.0, 0.0) {}

    BezierPoint(const Point &p) : point(p), control1(0.0, 0.0),
      control2(0.0, 0.0) {}

    Point point; // End point.  Start point is in the BezierPoint that
                 // came before it.

    // Todo: Set these to be coincident with point for non-curve points.
    Point control1;
    Point control2;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    BezierPoint,
    (Point, control1)
    (Point, control2)
    (Point, point)
)

typedef std::vector<BezierPoint> BezierVec;
typedef std::vector<BezierVec> Contours;

template <typename Iterator>
struct PathGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Contours()>
{
    ///////////////////////////
    // SVG is a damn monster //
    ///////////////////////////

    PathGrammar() : PathGrammar::base_type(path_data)
    {
        using qi::char_;
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::_val;
        using qi::_1;

        using phoenix::push_back;
        using phoenix::insert;
        using phoenix::begin;
        using phoenix::end;
        using phoenix::construct;
        using phoenix::val;

        using ascii::space;

        path_data = *space >> -moveto_drawto_command_groups
          >> *space;

        moveto_drawto_command_groups = moveto_drawto_command_group
          % *space;
        moveto_drawto_command_group = moveto[
           insert(_val, end(_val), begin(_1), end(_1))
          ] >> *space
          >> -drawto_commands[
           insert(_val, end(_val), begin(_1), end(_1))
          ];

        // Draw commands are (optionally) followed by a closepath
        // command.
        drawto_commands = (drawto_command[
           insert(_val, end(_val), begin(_1), end(_1))
          ] % *space) >> *space >> -closepath;
        drawto_command =  lineto | horizontal_lineto
          | vertical_lineto | curveto | smooth_curveto;

        moveto = ( char_('M') | char_('m') ) >> *space
          >> lineto_argument_sequence;

        closepath = (char_('Z') | char_('z'));

        lineto = ( char_('L') | char_('l') ) >> *space
          >> lineto_argument_sequence;
        lineto_argument_sequence = coordinate_pair[
           push_back(_val, construct<BezierPoint>(_1))
          ] % -comma_space;

        horizontal_lineto = ( char_('H') | char_('h') ) >> *space
          >> horizontal_lineto_argument_sequence;
        horizontal_lineto_argument_sequence = coordinate[
           push_back(_val, construct<BezierPoint>(_1, val(0.0)))
          ] % -comma_space;

        vertical_lineto = ( char_('V') | char_('v') ) >> *space
          >> vertical_lineto_argument_sequence;
        vertical_lineto_argument_sequence = coordinate[
           push_back(_val, construct<BezierPoint>(val(0.0), _1))
          ] % -comma_space;

        curveto = ( char_('C') | char_('c') ) >> *space
          >> curveto_argument_sequence;
        curveto_argument_sequence = curveto_argument % -comma_space;
        curveto_argument = coordinate_pair >> -comma_space
          >> coordinate_pair >> -comma_space >> coordinate_pair;

        smooth_curveto = ( char_('S') | char_('s') ) >> *space
          >> smooth_curveto_argument_sequence;
        smooth_curveto_argument_sequence = smooth_curveto_argument
          % -comma_space;
        smooth_curveto_argument = coordinate_pair >> -comma_space
          >> coordinate_pair;

        coordinate_pair = (double_ >> -comma_space >> double_);
        coordinate = double_;
        comma_space = (+space >> -char_(',') >> *space)
          | (char_(',') >> *space);
    }

    // Quadratic curves are not supported

    qi::rule<Iterator, Contours()> path_data;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Contours()> moveto_drawto_command_groups;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> moveto_drawto_command_group;

    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> drawto_commands;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> drawto_command;

    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> moveto;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> moveto_argument_sequence;

    qi::rule<Iterator> closepath;

    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> lineto;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> lineto_argument_sequence;

    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> horizontal_lineto;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()>
      horizontal_lineto_argument_sequence;

    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> vertical_lineto;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> vertical_lineto_argument_sequence;

    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> curveto;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> curveto_argument_sequence;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierPoint()> curveto_argument;

    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> smooth_curveto;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> smooth_curveto_argument_sequence;
    qi::rule<Iterator, BezierPoint()> smooth_curveto_argument;

    qi::rule<Iterator, Point()> coordinate_pair;
    qi::rule<Iterator, double()> coordinate;
    qi::rule<Iterator> comma_space;
};

#endif
```

The grammar is invoked like this:

```
typedef string::const_iterator StrItr;

PathGrammar<StrItr> grammar;

Contours paths;

StrItr startIt = pathData.begin();
StrItr endIt = pathData.end();
qi::parse(startIt, endIt, grammar, paths);

BOOST_FOREACH(BezierVec v, paths)
{
    cout << "Path:" << endl;
    BOOST_FOREACH(BezierPoint p, v)
    {
        cout << '\t' << p.point.x << ", " << p.point.y << endl;
    }
}
```

And this is my current test string:

```
M26.591,0L0,22.348l25.46,23.479L12.306,100l36.067-23.619L85.008,28.43L26.591,0z M30.553,34.23
    l-8.487-10.467l9.052-5.234l25.601,8.77l-3.109,12.729L30.553,34.23z
```

The string reformated to make it easier to read:

```
M 26.591,   0
L  0    ,  22.348
l 25.46 ,  23.479
L 12.306, 100
l 36.067, -23.619
L 85.008,  28.43
L 26.591,   0
z
M 30.553,  34.23
l -8.487, -10.467
l  9.052,  -5.234
l 25.601,   8.77
l -3.109,  12.729
L 30.553,  34.23
z
```

Here is the output:

```
Path:
    77, 0
    26.591, 0
    76, 0
    0, 22.348
    108, 0
    25.46, 23.479
    76, 0
    12.306, 100
    108, 0
    36.067, -23.619
    76, 0
    85.008, 28.43
    76, 0
    26.591, 0
Path:
    77, 0
    30.553, 34.23
    108, 0
    -8.487, -10.467
    108, 0
    9.052, -5.234
    108, 0
    25.601, 8.77
    108, 0
    -3.109, 12.729
    76, 0
    30.553, 34.23
```

The grammar is seeing the points, but it keeps putting in all these extra points and I have no idea where they're coming from.

### P.S.

I'm also wondering about a couple of my rules.  First there's this rule:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> drawto_commands;
qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> drawto_command;

...

drawto_commands = (drawto_command[
   insert(_val, end(_val), begin(_1), end(_1))
  ] % *space) >> *space >> -closepath;
```

I want to have the results of `(drawto_command % *space)` as a single vector instead of a vector of vectors.  As far as I can tell, I have to do this manually with Phoenix.  Is that the case?

I have a similar thing with my moveto rules:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> moveto_drawto_command_group;
qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> moveto;
qi::rule<Iterator, BezierVec()> moveto_argument_sequence;

...

moveto_drawto_command_group = moveto[
   insert(_val, end(_val), begin(_1), end(_1))
  ] >> *space
  >> -drawto_commands[
   insert(_val, end(_val), begin(_1), end(_1))
  ];
```

I have two rules that give a BezierVec, which I want to combine into a single BezierVec for the third rule.  So far the only way to do this appears to be manual insertion with Phoenix.  Is there no simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional values in the output are generated from the ASCII characters `'M' == 77`, `'L' == 76`, `'l' == 108`, etc. This happens as you're matching those using `char_('M')`, etc., which exposes the matched value as a `char` attribute. The compiler happily assigns this to the `double` values in the output array. In order to avoid this, use either `lit('M')`, or just `'M'`. Neither of those exposes any attribute, making the expressions neutral in terms of generated values.

A second thing which could be improved is to remove the `*space` constructs from all over the place and to switch to phrase parsing (see the documentation of the `phrase_parse` API function [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parse_api/iterator_api.html)). If you supply a `space` parser component as the skipper parameter and add a `space_type` skipper template type parameter to all of your rule's, you'll get the same effect as having the `*space` constructs interspersed in your grammar. For instance:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, Contours(), space_type> path_data;
```

If you have parts of the input which is not allowed to contain whitespace, those still can be embedded into `lexeme[]` directives. See [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/02/24/parsing-skippers-and-skipping-parsers/) for more information.

---

Your P.S:

In order to combine all vectors returned from `drawto_command` you could employ a trick forcing Spirit.Qi to append to the provided (left hand side attribute) vector:

```
 drawto_commands = +drawto_command >> -closepath;
```

which is already assuming you switched to phrase parsing, thus I removed the `*space` constructs. Why does this work? Well, Spirit.Qi has a special attribute propagation rule for sequences, forcing it to append all attributes exposed by its elements into a provided container if all elements of this sequence either expose this attribute type or a container of those attribute types. No semantic action is required here. Note, this works only for sequences, not single element right hand side constructs.

Your second related question can be solved in a similar manner:

```
moveto_drawto_command_group = moveto >> -drawto_commands;
```

again, no semantic actions are required.